# scipy.optimize.brentq fails to converge in a simple case

Tags: python, scipy

As a first attempt to use `scipy.optimize.brentq` I have tried the following:

```
scipy.optimize.brentq(lambda x: x**3, -0.09, 0.01)
```

and the output was

```
RuntimeError: Failed to converge after 100 iterations.
```

Of course, I can let it try more iterations, make the interval shorter, etc... however, this is a well-behaved function, and I have used the default number of iterations on a relatively small interval. Was it too much to expect a solution in these settings?

I'll add that according to scipy's documentation, this algorithm is the recommended one for general use in one dimensional problems when an interval where the function changes sign has been found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only *just* fails

```
scipy.optimize.brentq(lambda x: x**3, -0.09, 0.01,maxiter=105)
```

gives

```
-1.3399668957297373e-13
```

It works perfectly if you choose this,larger, interval so the fact that you've chosen a small interval has not made it easier:

```
scipy.optimize.brentq(lambda x: x**3, -1, 1)
```

gives

```
0
```

Furthermore, it got this solution in 2 iterations:

```
(re,obj) = scipy.optimize.brentq(lambda x: x**3, -1, 1,full_output=True)
obj.iterations
```

gives

```
2
```

I suspect, however, that this is because the root is in the midpoint of the chosen interval. If we break the symmetry of the interval, things are not so good

```
(re,obj) = scipy.optimize.brentq(lambda x: x**3, -0.99, 1,full_output=True,maxiter=200)
obj.iterations
```

gives

```
115
```

I think that the problem is that the root of x^3 is also a point of inflection and many root-finding algorithms have problems in such situations.

Note that there is nothing wrong with scipy's implementation of Brent's method. You get the same behaviour if you try it in Mathematica, for example.

Comment: You're probably right about the symmetry: `scipy.optimize.brentq(lambda x: x**3, -9, 1)` fails... thanks!